# Problems making a 3-parameter Ajax request with different types - Asp.net Core MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I need to make an Ajax request with 3 parameters (A Model, an Integer and an Enum), but I'm getting null for the properties of the Model, value 0 for the integer parameter and Enum. The curious thing is that if I just pass Model (personContactViewModel) alone and converting it to the AJAX query block (data: JSON.stringify (personContactViewModel)), it works. The problem is that passing 3 parameters, none of them work. Does anyone know how to help me?
A hug to everyone!

[image]

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("pessoa-gerenciar/changeFormaContato")]
public IActionResult ChangeFormaContato([FromBody] PessoaContatoViewModel pessoaContatoViewModel, int formaContatoIdChange, PessoaNatureza pessoaNatureza)
{
    //ViewBag.indice_new = indice;
    //return PartialView("~/Views/Pessoa/PessoaContato/_PessoaContatoAdd.cshtml", _pessoaContatoAppService.CreateNew(pessoaNatureza, formaContatoId));
    return null;
}

public class PessoaContatoViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int PessoaId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Forma de Contato")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Escolha a Forma de Contato")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public int FormaContatoId { get; set; }       

    [DisplayName("Forma de Contato")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Selecione uma Forma de Contato")]
    public int FormaContatoTipoId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Contato")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo Contato é obrigatório")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} deve ter no máximo {1} caracteres")]
    public string Contato { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Observação")]
    [MaxLength(150, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} deve ter no máximo {1} caracteres")]
    public string Observacao { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Principal")]
    public bool ContatoPrincipal { get; set; }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var pessoaNatureza = $('#pessoaNatureza').val();
var formaContatoIdChange = $(this).closest('.row').find('.sel-forma-contato').val(); //Forma de contato selecionada depois de alterar
var formaContatoAtual = $(this).closest('.row').find('.sel-contato-tipo').val() != '' ? $(this).closest('.row').find('.sel-contato-tipo').val() : '0';
var idAtual = $(this).closest('.row').find('.hid-id').val() != '' ? $(this).closest('.row').find('.hid-id').val() : '0';
var pessoaIdAtual = $(this).closest('.row').find('.hid-pessoaId').val() != '' ? $(this).closest('.row').find('.hid-pessoaId').val() : '0';
var contatoAtual = $(this).closest('.row').find('.txt-contato').val();
var observacaoAtual = $(this).closest('.row').find('.txt-observacao').val();
var contatoPrincipalAtual = $(this).closest('.row').find('.ckb-contato-principal').is(":checked");

var pessoaContatoViewModel = {
    Id: parseInt(idAtual),
    PessoaId: parseInt(pessoaIdAtual),
    FormaContatoId: parseInt(formaContatoIdPrevious),
    FormaContatoTipoId: parseInt(formaContatoAtual),
    Contato: contatoAtual,
    Observacao: observacaoAtual,
    ContatoPrincipal: contatoPrincipalAtual
};

$.ajax({
    url: "/pessoa-gerenciar/changeFormaContato",
    type: "POST",
    data: {pessoaContatoViewModel: JSON.stringify(pessoaContatoViewModel), formaContatoIdChange: formaContatoIdChange, pessoaNatureza: pessoaNatureza},
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",

    success: function (result) {
        formaContatoIdPrevious = "0";
    },
    error: function () {
        formaContatoIdPrevious = "0";
        alert("Oops! Algo deu errado.");
    }
});
```

Comment: As per my knowledge you can not send model with separate parameter, so to resolve your problem you can add your other two params in your model and pass only that model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the json object when `contentType: "application/json"` ,put multiple properties in a object

```
var model = {
            pessoaContatoViewModel: pessoaContatoViewModel,
            formaContatoIdChange: formaContatoIdChange,
            pessoaNatureza: pessoaNatureza 
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "/pessoa-gerenciar/changeFormaContato",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(model),
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",

            success: function (result) {
                formaContatoIdPrevious = "0";
            },
            error: function () {
                formaContatoIdPrevious = "0";
                alert("Oops! Algo deu errado.");
            }
        });
    }
```

Controller:

```
    public class TestModel
    {
        public PessoaContatoViewModel pessoaContatoViewModel { get; set; }
        public int formaContatoIdChange { get; set; }
        public PessoaNatureza pessoaNatureza { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("pessoa-gerenciar/changeFormaContato")]
    public IActionResult ChangeFormaContato([FromBody] TestModel model)
    {
        //ViewBag.indice_new = indice;
        //return PartialView("~/Views/Pessoa/PessoaContato/_PessoaContatoAdd.cshtml", _pessoaContatoAppService.CreateNew(pessoaNatureza, formaContatoId));
        return null;
    }
```